# Does Kubernetes have webhook or similar functionality?

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, kubernetes-health-check

I'd like a webserver to be notified if Kubernetes kills a pod and for what reason e.g. DEADLINE_EXCEEDED or OOM. Does Kubernetes have webhook functionality for this or some other mechanism where I can be told when it does something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a webhook per-se, however there are kubernetes events that you can listen to.

Quick google turned up [this article](https://solinea.com/blog/tapping-kubernetes-events)